# Getting Selected Items From WinForm ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox in a WinForm with multiselect enabled.

The selected items appear to be stored in an object, how to I get their values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy, depending on what type you stored:

```
foreach (MyItemType item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
   ...
}
```

Because this is an older, non-generic collection it is better not to use `var` to declare the item variable. That would only get you a reference of type `object`.

You can also use other properties like:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code to display the selected item from the `ListBox` - for WinForm app...

```
string s = listbox1.Text; //replace listbox1 with your listbox control
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the SelectedItems property.

```
foreach (var selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected items are found in the [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) property. These are the objects that you added to the list box, so you can cast the objects to their respective type and access any members that way:

```
// get the first selected item, cast it to MyClass
MyClass item = listBox.SelectedItems[0] as MyClass;
if (item != null)
{
    // use item here
}
```

Comment: This would get the first/single selection, but it still needs to check the size of the `SelectedItems` collection, otherwise no selection will make this throw index out of bounds.

Comment: @Jon: you are of course correct. My answer is not an attempt to be a complete guide on how to use the `SelectedItems` property, but rather to answer the question *The selected items appear to be stored in an object, how to I get their values*.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to add a small warning for anyone tempted to copy/paste this code.