# Foreach selected item in Listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialog that is used to select which forms to show. Originally it was just being selected from a combo box, but now we need to select multiple, so we changed it to a list box.

Here is the method that we used for the combo box:

```
if (view.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{          
    if (view.FormType == "Form1")
        return new Form1_Controller();
    else if (view.FormType == "Form2")
        return new Form2_Controller();
    else if (view.FormType == "Form3")
        return new Form3_Controller();
    else return null;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

How can we encapsulate this in a loop that will return a controller for each selection?

For example, I have tried something like

```
foreach (ListBoxItem listItem in view.ListBox1)
{
    //do if (view.FormType == "Form1")
}
```

But I don't know the right syntax to use.

Comment: Assuming you are using WPF, please add the XAML for ListBox1

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Sorry, I'm using WinForms, not WPF

Comment: do you want to show all forms simultaneously or 1 after another?

Comment: @Anand All the selected forms together. So if the user selects 1 and 3, it will bring up both forms together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open all forms simultaneously, I would try a different approach something like this

```
ArrayList controllersSelected = new ArrayList();

foreach (var item in view.ListBox1.SelectedItems)
    GetSelectedItem(item.Value, out controllersSelected);

//Your logic to display selected forms simultaneously
DisplaySimultaneousForms(controllersSelected);

private void GetSelectedItem(formName, out ArrayList list)
{
  if (view.FormType == "Form1")
    list.Add(new Form1_Controller());
  else if (view.FormType == "Form2")
    list.Add(new Form2_Controller());
  else if (view.FormType == "Form3")
    list.Add(new Form3_Controller());
}
```

Comment: @Ben, Refer this question for displaying multiple forms simultaneously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300887/run-two-winform-windows-simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code :

```
foreach (var item in view.ListBox1.SelectedItems)
{        
    ShowForm(item.Value);
}

private void ShowForm(formName)
{
  if (view.FormType == "Form1")
    return new Form1_Controller();
  else if (view.FormType == "Form2")
    return new Form2_Controller();
  else if (view.FormType == "Form3")
    return new Form3_Controller();
  else return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: You can use var instead of that and also using SelectedItems of listbox

Comment: @Anand, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960698/getting-selected-items-from-winform-listbox

Comment: @Peyman, your code missed the "in" keyword in foreach loop, I just edited that, also this will not open all the forms simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

use `SelectedItems`:

```
foreach (var item view.ListBox1.SelectedItems)
    SelectForm(item.ToString());


void SelectForm(string value)
{
    if(value == "Form1")
        return new Form1_Controller();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i++) 
      {
           switch (listBox1 .Items [i].ToString ())
                {
                    case "FirstForm":
                        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                        frm2.Show();
                        break;
                    case "SecondForm":
                        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                        frm3.Show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
               }
       }
  }
```